# ¿De qué manera el comando openssl passwd genera el hash para una contraseña aparentemente vacía?

Tags: openssl

Estoy experimentando con el comando `passwd` de `openssl` para generar el hash de una contraseña. De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Passwd(1)) este genera el hash al pasarle como parámetro la contraseña o a partir de una lista de contraseñas. Sin embargo, si no le paso la contraseña como parámetro:

```
openssl passwd
```

descubro que me genera un hash. También encuentro que cada vez que ejecuto el comando me genera un hash diferente. Mis preguntas son:

1. ¿Está generando el hash de una contraseña 'vacía' o de alguna contraseña generada de algún otro modo?
2. Si el hash de una contraseña es único, ¿por qué genera un hash diferente cada vez que ejecuto el mismo comando?

Answer (score 0):

1. Generaría el hash de una contraseña vacía con un salt.
2. Con el fin de que un atacante no pueda determinar, por ejemplo, que dos contraseñas de usuario son iguales aún estando cifradas (esto es aplicable a cualquier otro tipo de dato) se le añade un salt aleatorio a la contraseña en cuestión y se cifran juntos. Aunque la contraseña es la misma, el salt es distinto cada vez y de ahí que el hash resultante sea diferente.

Comment: Gracias, ¿el salt lo genera de manera aleatoria?

Comment: Revisando [el código](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/passwd.c) parece que si no se le pasa por parámetro genera una secuencia pseudoaleatoria, así que la respuesta a tu pregunta sería que sí. También puedes usar el parámetro `-salt` para pasarle un salt por parámetro. Por razones de seguridad, el salt debe ser lo más aleatorio posible, asegúrate que usas un generador seguro en caso de especificarlo tú.

Comment: El método que usan para generar el salt en passwd es [RAND_bytes](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:RAND_bytes(3)). Una forma de generar una secuencia pseudoaleatoria desde la terminal es usando el comando [RAND](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Rand(1)) de OpenSSL.